# Manga about main character being the sister of the emperor

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I am looking for an isekai manga that I read some time ago. The main character (MC) is the sister of the emperor. He has golden hair. He becomes the emperor at a young age and brings his sister with him. The MC is reincarnated in the novel she read before dying.

I remember an incident where they were at a ball and their step sister gave the MC an earring set that was worn by maids to humiliate her. Her little brother sold the emperor pen to give her pearl earrings, but he was scammed as those were fake.

Comment: Do you remember how the main character died? Which site you mite have read this on? And did her little brother (the MC's little brother? The step-sister's?) sell the emperor a pen? Or is that meant to be another word?

Comment: Some superficial resemblance to "[Mad Emperor's Pet Sister](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/mad-emperors-pet-sister/)", but that's a webnovel. I haven't found a manga or manhua of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Tyrant's Sister](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-tyrants-sister)*, aka *Living as the Tyrant's Older Sister*. It is licensed in English by tapas.

> If there’s one thing that ruins a good story, it’s a cliché! Handsome prince? Lame. Damsel in distress? Yawn. Knight in shining armor? Depends... How good is he in bed? Wait, HUH?! Well, Yuna Han is out to make sure her sister’s story is anything but a cliché, only now she'll have to live inside of it. And luckily, she plays a fairly minor role. Her only crime is being the main villain's older sister! Can she manage to save both her sister's story AND her own neck before we reach the final page?

The main character reincarnates in a story her sister wrote, as the older sister of the main villain, a future tyrant emperor. Both she and her brother have golden blonde hair. Her brother becomes emperor at a young age after their mother dies. He's crowned; the MC knows she'll die if she goes along with him, but is forced to accompany him.

[image: Blonde hair siblings]  [image: Emperor]

The scene with the earring involves the MC's step sister, the heroine of the original novel, gifting the sister fancy-looking gems that are actually quite cheap. It's a common trend for the maids of noble women to wear them, but not the actual nobles. She falls for it, until the male lead notices, and tosses one of them into the lake so she can't wear them to the ball and embarrass herself.

The pen incident is separate; a crooked merchant tries to sell her brother common pearls, insisting they're extremely rare and valuable, in example for an heirloom pen. He falls for it, until his sister finds out and forces the merchant to return it.

Comment: I'll try to add images later in the day. The pen and pearl incidents are probably too difficult to capture in screenshots.

Comment: thank you for telling me the story name even though i wasn't able to give a detailed explanation